# Yii2: запуск модального окна при beforeSave = false

Tags: yii2

Добрый день.

Перед отправкой формы необходимо запускать функцию из другого компонента, которая возвращает результат в виде многомерного массива, где содержатся сведения об ошибках и обновленных значениях полей.

Далее необходимо:

1. в форме вывести модальное окно, содержащее ошибки массива (если они есть) и предотвратить отправку
2. обновить значения полей формы и отправить ее (если ошибок в массиве не обнаружено).

Последний вариант реализуем с помощью метода

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {

        $result = Yii::$app->MyComponent->MyFunction($this->attributes);

        if (empty($result['errors'])) {
            foreach ($result['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Как правильно будет реализовать первый вариант, когда в массиве содержатся ошибки?

Comment: Если информацию вы хотите вывести модальным окном, то тут скорее всего вам придется делать отправку формы через ajax, в случае ошибок, возвращать их, вызывать средствами javascript модальное окно и выводить их там

Comment: @madfan41k, Ок, но если повесить ajax-запрос на событие submit, то он будет реагировать в том числе и на ошибки валидации полей формы, которые мне не нужны.

Comment: ну так уберите эту валидацию
'enableClientValidation'=>false

Comment: @madfan41k, в том смысле, что валидация задействована, но отлавливать нужно только ответ функции компонента.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых у вас неправильная логика.
Если вы хотите сделать до валидации данной формы провести некоторое действие со сторонним компонентом то лучше делать это так:
1) Обьявляете beforeValidate, туда ложите обьект данной формы, и отправляете компанент. ( потому что beforeSave отрабатывается после валидации , а если валидация не прошла, то он возвращает вас обратно с ошибками )
2) Компанент возвращает вам свои валидационные данные ( в неком виде ) , вы парсите его и если там есть ошибки или что там вам нужно, создаете обьект вашей формы и прерываете исполнение текущего сценария и отправляете пользователя на туже страницу, только вставляете кусок шаблона с вашей модалкой. ( можно сделать через скрытый setflash к примеру )

перечитал еще раз ваш вопрос, не совсем понятно что конкретно вы добиваетесь.
но исходя из этого

> функцию из другого компонента, которая возвращает результат в виде многомерного массива, где содержатся сведения об ошибках и обновленных значениях полей

то вам просто нужно унаследовать валидатор , который будет обрабатывать текущее поле, отправлять данные в компонент, он будет возвращать ошибку \ или не возвращать, и вы будите тогда переопределять error message

Comment: Благодарю вас за развернутый ответ. Мое приложение общается с каталогом ActiveDirectory. Запросы в AD (функции) хранятся в созданном мной компоненте (классе). В модели формы для некоторых полей заданы кастомные правила валидации: делается запрос в AD и возвращается результат, на основании которого затем выводится переопределенная ошибка (если есть). Так вот при успешной валидации всех полей должен отработать нужный мне запрос в AD, вернуть результат, на основании которого форма либо сохранится, либо будет выведено модальное окно с возникшими ошибками.

Comment: вы делаете тоже самое, только обращаетесь к методу который работает с ad